# How do I setup a static html page in rails without having to configure routes, controller, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on layout and html-structure of a single .html page and would just like to hit it via http://localhost/page.html where it still has access to my resources, etc.  I tried putting it inside public/ folder but can't seem to serve it up unless I configure routes, etc.  Is there any way to do this without configuring all the routes, etc.??

Comment: IMHO this is not the way to develop web applications in rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work. Are you sure that you're calling proper path ( i.e. http://localhost/page.html and not http://localhost/public/page.html )? If it doesn't work in your app try creating a new one — if it works there it means something (a gem perhaps?) messed up Rails' native routing. If not then your Rails installation is messed up by itself.